# how to match a wildcard in openAM

Tags: wildcard, openam

I have a question: '*' in url policy can not match a '*' in url.
When there is a '*' in the url , the request will be forbidden by openAM. I don't know how to resolve it.

For example:

```
Similarly the policy 'http:// www.example.com:8000/**?*' ,
matches 'http://www.example.com:8000/WebApp/index.htm?ttt=1',
but not matches 'http://www.example.com:8000/WebApp/index.htm?ttt=1*1'
```

why?
How to resolve this?

Comment: the question is that a wildcard in url policy can not match a wildcard in url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into [OPENAM-8134](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-8134), you will need to upgrade to one of the fixed versions.